# how to parallel ssh over ssh proxy with ssh-agent for authentication in python?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, proxy

I've got a project where I need to ssh to a large number of servers to invoke a command on a frequent basis.  I thought that this would be possible from within a python script, however my requirements seem to eliminate all the potential solutions.  I can only access the servers from an intermediate bastion server, and only with an ssh public key which is being forwarded with an ssh agent.  Thus my requirements are:

- parallel ssh, so that I'm not waiting hours to run the command to completion on all the servers
- ssh public key support, as I cannot use password authentication
- ssh proxying support, as I cannot ssh directly to the servers without going through an ssh proxy server
- ssh agent support, as I need to have my (pre-loaded) ssh public key sent through the proxy server to the server

paramiko appears to provide all of the above with the exception of the first requirement (parallel ssh support).  I found a parallel-ssh module ( https://github.com/pkittenis/parallel-ssh ) which acts as a thin wrapper around paramiko, but alas, it appears to lack API support for just about everything other than parallel ssh and public key auth.

Here's what I've got right now, which works on a few local servers which don't require proxying or ssh-agent to access:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import sys
if 'threading' in sys.modules:
        raise Exception('threading module loaded before patching!')
import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_thread()
import paramiko
from pssh import ParallelSSHClient

paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")
hosts = ['ocb100','netllama']
client_key = paramiko.DSSKey.from_private_key_file('/home/netllama/.ssh/id_dsa')
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, pkey=client_key)

cmds = client.exec_command('uptime')
```

Comment: Consider Fabric -- it's specifically designed for running commands on lots of ssh'd servers. http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: You can run many paramiko clients simultaneously in different threads. Is that what you need?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the overhead of managing threads, but if that's the only way to get where I need to go, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel-ssh module you previously mentioned can satisfy your requirements. Specifically for proxying and agent forwarding:

- SSH proxying support - Native proxying and tunneling support, also asynchronous
- SSH agent forwarding - Enabled by default. `forward_ssh_agent=True` on creating a ParallelSSH object.

Your example using ParallelSSH:

```
from pssh import ParallelSSHClient
hosts = ['ocb100','netllama']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, proxy_host='bastion')
output = client.run_command('uptime')
for host in output:
    for line in output[host]['stdout']:
        print(line)
```

SSH keys for the user executing the above are loaded automatically from a running SSH agent, you do not need to specify the `pkey` argument.

If you need to change the user you login as you can set the `user` argument, for example, `ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='netllama')`.

SSH agent forwarding support was added to ParallelSSH on September 4th according to [this issue](https://github.com/pkittenis/parallel-ssh/issues/8).

ParallelSSH already uses gevent to perform all network requests asynchronously per documentation, it does not use threading or multi processing unlike, for example, fabric. You therefor do not need those gevent imports either.

Documentation for ParallelSSH is [here](http://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.org/en/latest).

Edit: Updated for latest library API